# file too big to upload with google drive api: ssl.SSLWantWriteError: The operation did not complete (write) (_ssl.c:2427)

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I'm testing some code with the google drive api to implement it in the future on my school project.
what I have right now is: I have a code that uploads a file, then that file is given a id followed by another code that downloads the same file from my drive.

Everything was working fine, but when i went to test the same code with a 500MB file (its roughly the size of the file im gonna need to upload and then download form my school project program) it gives me this error "ssl.SSLWantWriteError: The operation did not complete (write) (_ssl.c:2427)"

From my understanding its a wifi related error, i had this problem before when uploading a 45 mb file but i switched to my hotspot and it worked, but now even with the hotspot it does not work, is it still really wifi?

here's the code

```
`
from __future__ import print_function 
import os

from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload



SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'C:\\Users\\danie\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\PAP\\service account file\\iris-face-models-565de449aa27.json'

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES
)

drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

target_folder_id = '1MAM4CPDMbqpzP5rZb1Zw0A15r4U7B4Kv' 
file_metadata = {
    'name': '512MB.zip',
    'parents': [target_folder_id] 
}
media = MediaFileUpload('C:\\Users\\danie\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\PAP\\testeupload\\512MB.zip', mimetype='text/plain')

file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id').execute()

print(f'File ID: {file["id"]}')
`
```

i thought about dividing the file in my project but since its a trained face recognition model it wouldnt end well.

Comment: From the docs: "While it is possible to upload the full 5 TiB in a single upload request, such long-running uploads are more likely to experience failures; resumable uploads are the recommended method for uploading large objects." . Docs about resumable uploads: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/resumable-uploads#python . Also "text/plain" does not look likr the right media type